# I am getting a error:cannot find symbol when compiling

Tags: java, if-statement, compiler-errors

I am trying to calculate and round up with an IF statement, the code is below. The error comes on the line:    if (partterms < 6)

```
   // Setup Array List for Course CU
        ArrayList<Double> coursecu = new ArrayList<Double>();
  // Read inputs for Course Units and Sum the Value
        System.out.println("Please enter Individual Course CU values, Q to quit:");
        Scanner in2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (in.hasNextDouble())
        {
            coursecu.add(in.nextDouble());
        } 
        double sum = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < coursecu.size(); i++)
        {
            sum = sum + coursecu.get(i);
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Total Credit Units Required for Graduation");
        System.out.println(sum);
  // Calculate the Number of Terms to Completion
       {
          double fullterm = sum / planned_units; // Sets Whole Terms 
          double partterm = sum % planned_units; // Sets Partial Terms
        }
        if (partterm < 6)
        {
            number_terms = fullterms++;
        }
        else
        {
            number_terms = fullterms;
        }
```

Comment: The variable is named `partterm`, not `partterms`.

Comment: Thanks Jeroen, I changed it back but it still gives the error.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a code with a small typo. It will not be useful for anyone else visiting the site.

Comment: Maroun, I am trying to calculate and round up the term number based upon the partterm value. Does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks dasblinkenlight but fixing the typo did not change the error result

Comment: This question was prompted by a problem that is unrelated to the actual question asked. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was solved by the asker in a manner unlikely to be relevant to others. This confusion can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Answer (score 5):

```
{ ← 
    double fullterm = sum / planned_units; // Sets Whole Terms 
    double partterm = sum % planned_units; // Sets Partial Terms
} ←
```

Remove `{` and `}` and the variables will be known outside this weird block.

Comment: I don't think that will change something the brackets are just useless

Comment: @яша They limit the life of the variable to the block, only.

Comment: nevertheless I have upvoted though it helps to improve the code

Comment: @яша Not only improve the code, it's actually the reason of the error.

Comment: That did it!! wow, those two brackets, I am not sure why I had them in it. Thanks Maroun!!

Comment: @ᴍarounᴍaroun That's weird I didn't know that, Thanks for clarifying, one minute, if you create new unnecessary brackets, what would that do ? I mean in the design point of view ?

Comment: @яша Using them like this is to limit the variable scope.. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563030/anonymous-code-blocks-in-java) post.