# New Java Programmer, whats wrong with this program?

Tags: java, eclipse

It gets to the point where it has to print the line `System.out.printf("%4s%22s%24s\n","Year"...)`, and then just stops without printing.

```
public class WorldPopulationGrowth {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in);
        long BasePopulation; //The base, or current population
        double GrowthRate; //The rate of increase
        double GrowthResult; // The pop after growth rate increase

        //Time to obtain the numbers needed for Calculation
        //Specifically, the growth rate and the base population
        System.out.println("Welcome to the world population calculator");
        System.out.print("Enter the current world population:");
        BasePopulation = input.nextLong();
        System.out.println("Enter the current growth rate: (e.g, 1.14% would be .0114): ");
        GrowthRate = input.nextDouble();
        int Year = 1; //I need this for the next part
        System.out.printf("%4s%22s%24s\n", "Year", "Estimated Population", "Change from prior Year");
        while (Year <= 75); {// Start of the while
            GrowthResult = BasePopulation * (1 + GrowthRate);
            System.out.printf("%4d%22d%24d\n", Year, (long) GrowthResult, (long) GrowthResult - BasePopulation);
            BasePopulation = (long) GrowthResult;
        }//End of the while
    }//End of public static
}//End of class
```

Comment: Quick tip: your variables should all start with a lower case letter.  For example BasePopulation should be basePopulation.

Answer (score 7):

You've got a semicolon after your `while` loop. That semicolon is an [empty statement](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch02_06.htm#INDEX-320), and *that's* what gets executed in the loop. After that, you have an [anonymous block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563030) (which is what you want to be executed in the loop). It's equivalent to this:

```
while (Year <= 75) {
    // empty
}
{
    // anonymous block
    GrowthResult = BasePopulation * (1 + GrowthRate);
    ...
```

The fix is to remove the semicolon.

Comment: Thanks very much! I probably should have done this a more simpler way too.

Answer (score 2):

Try removing semicolon from this line

`while (Year <= 75); {// Start of the while`

Should be:

`while (Year <= 75) {// Start of the while`