# for - try combined loop?

Tags: java, for-loop, try-catch

Working with some legacy code, and encountered this:

```
    File file = new File()
    File[] files = file.listFiles();
    for(int i=0;i<files.length;i++)
        try {
            {
                System.out.println("Do stuff");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

it compiles and runs, but I don't know which loop is inside the other, or why it works.

Comment: I only see one loop... Can you point out where you think the second is?

Comment: Something tells me that `File file = new File()` doesn't compile, for at least two reasons...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code

```
    File file = new File();
    File[] files = file.listFiles();
    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) 
        try {
            {
                System.out.println("Do stuff");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Is same as this one

```
    File file = new File();
    File[] files = file.listFiles();
    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        try {
            {
                System.out.println("Do stuff");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And same as this one

```
    File file = new File();
    File[] files = file.listFiles();
    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Do stuff");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Java allows you to have some "extra" brackets, but it does not change anything (well it change the scope of variables if you declare them inside it, but this is not the case)

Answer (score 1):

`try-catch` isn't a loop, it's just a construct that executes the `try` block (once) and the possibly the `catch` block(s).

If you break it down, here's what's going on:

- for each index `i` in the `files` array

  - do one thing, a `try-catch`

    - the `try` block itself has an ["anonymous block"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563030/anonymous-code-blocks-in-java) (the block created by the curlies inside the `try` -- it starts at the second curly brace after the word `try`)

      - the anonymous block has one statement, `System.out.println("Do stuff");`
    - the `catch` block prints the exception's stack trace (if an exception thrown, of course)