# Java Syntax: Code block after semicolon?

Tags: java, android

I'm programming android for a while and it's first time i see this syntax:

```
private void createMenu(Menu menu)
{
    MenuItem mnu1 = menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Item 1");
    {
        menu1.setAlphabeticShortcut('a');
        menu1.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    }
}
```

After that line 3 is closed by a semicolon, at line 4 we see a block of code. what kind of syntax is it?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563030/anonymous-code-blocks-in-java

Comment: First of all mnu1 is misspelled. Second... why are you open { if you don't have a if statement, listener, method, etc? is unnecessary.

Comment: Sorry re-opened by mistake. Closing again.