# What happens when "if" statement is ended with a semi colon

Tags: java, loops, if-statement

In a program, I needed an `if` statement and by mistake, I put semicolon at the end of the statement. However, there were neither compile-time error nor run-time error. I tried to figure out what this code means but hopeless.

```
if (i == 10); 
{
    System.out.println("It is here");
    break;
}
```

If you enlighten me on this topic, that will be appreciated.

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14112515/semicolon-at-end-of-if-statement

Comment: It just does nothing. The code in brackets will be executed regardless of the if condition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `if` statement has nothing to do with the following block:

```
if (i == 10);
```

This is a valid statement as `;` denotes [an empty statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.6): `if (i == 10)` then do nothing.

```
{
    System.out.println("It is here");
    break;
}
```

This is a valid [code block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563030/anonymous-code-blocks-in-java). It is syntactically correct although it does not help a lot in this case. This block will be executed in all cases and is not affected by the `if` statement above.

Comment: I do not get the idea of acceptance this statement by the compiler. If "if (i == 10);" does not do anything, how is it allowed ?

Comment: @KenVors It is syntactically valid. It does not do anything, but `int i;` doesn't do anything either if `i` is never used again.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Ok, you are right int i; does not do anything but there is a possibility of using the i in the future. But, the thing is not same with the if. You cannot use such an if statement in no way in the future.

Comment: @KenVors The task of a compiler is to compile code, not to make sense of it. Okay, another example: `if(1 == 2) throw new RuntimeException("Oops!");`. This is valid as well and will never be executed as `1` is never equal to `2`. And another example: `for(int i = 5; i > 5; i++) { ... }` will never even run once because `5` is never greater than `5`. Not everything that compiles has to make sense ;)

Comment: Ok, I got your point and you are right but may be, I could not express good myself. (English is not my mother language:) In your examples, The code blocks are logical but you write them illogical (from a human view). But, the same situation with if, it is illogical from both computer view and human view. The same compiler warns you when you write " while(true); ". I just wanted to learn what is special with  if statement. However, I learned that nothing special with it. Thank you for your answer and it is selected as the answer in any case ;)