# How to add a string to an array with an if statement?

Tags: java, arraylist

Does this way of adding a string to an Array List work? When a player is level 2+ , a new enemy should be added to the Array List. I am only showing the code that is important to the question but basically a random enemy is chosen from the Array List for the player to face.

```
int level = player.level;

ArrayList<String> enemies2 = new ArrayList<String>(); {

    if (level >= 2) {
    enemies2.add("Giant");
    }

    enemies2.add("Skeleton");
    enemies2.add("Zombie");
    enemies2.add("Warrior");
    enemies2.add("Assassin");
    enemies2.add("Reaper");
    enemies2.add("Archer");
}
```

Comment: Despite being confusing code to read: the `{..}` here is an [*anonymous code block*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563030/anonymous-code-blocks-in-java) and the braces are unnecessary; it should not be confused with any sort of initializer. Why "doesn't it work"? Make sure the question is clear - and try out things; as the compiler (and actual execution of the program) will provide useful feedback.

Comment: Okay thank you, my eclipse compiler tells me to put curly brackets after the ArrayList and at the end.

Comment: Hmm. Arbitrary "style" setting I suppose, *sigh*.

Comment: I think that your compiler is saying to you use something like: new ArrayList<String>() {{ add("Giant"); add("Skeleton"); }};

Comment: Your if statement needs to be within a method as does your enemies2.add() methods. Perhaps within a initialize() method or what the heck...even main() method.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend

```
int level = player.level;

ArrayList<String> enemies2 = new ArrayList<String>();
enemies2.add("Skeleton");
enemies2.add("Zombie");
enemies2.add("Warrior");
enemies2.add("Assassin");
enemies2.add("Reaper");
enemies2.add("Archer");
if(level >= 2) { enemies2.add("Giant"); } // if you want it on one line
```

For double brace initialization you don't need the enemies2 before the add()

```
ArrayList<String> enemies2 = new ArrayList<String>() {{
    add("Skeleton");
    add("Zombie");
    add("Warrior");
    add("Assassin");
    add("Reaper");
    add("Archer");
}};
```

Comment: Thank you but I am starting to realize that my issue is the fact that the "level" is what is breaking the program. I am getting that value from another class and it does not like that. When I removed the initialization of the other class which was Player player = new Player(); and got rid of the level variable, it worked.