# Why is this not a syntax error / What syntax is that

Tags: java, syntax

I'm having difficulties in finding a duplicate or explanation, as I don't know the name for the syntax.

Earlier today, I wrote a piece of code containing an extra `;`:

```
if (condition); {
    try {
        // something
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // something
    }
}
```

I know that the if statement is interrupted by the `;`. What I'm interested in is the block

```
{
    // something
}
```

How is that block (`{}`) without a leading `if`, `for`, ... called, and what can I use it for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `{}` blocks on their own, you don't (necessarily) need `if`, `else` or other keywords for that.

Such blocks are useful to structure code or, for instance, to limit scopes of local variables, ex.:

```
{
     int myVar = ...;
}
```

`myVar` will not be visible/accessible outside of the block so that might make it easier to read this code as you don't have to consider `myVar` outside of the block.

Answer (score 3):

It is called (Anonymous) **Code Block**.

There is an SO post on the motivation of the feature.

[Anonymous code blocks in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563030/anonymous-code-blocks-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

It is simply a compound statement. The reason your typo is not a syntax error is that an `if` statement, by definition, is followed by *exactly* one statement. That could be an empty statement (`;`), a simple statement (`x = x + 1`), or a compound statement (`{ ... }`).

A compound statement by itself (rather than being used as the body of and `if`, `for`, etc) is typically used to define a scope in which a variable can be defined with a precise life span.

```
// No foo out here
{
   int foo;
   ...
}
// No foo here either
```