# Java if statment ending with a semi-colim

Tags: java, syntax

I have encountered the following strange behavior in Java using **jdk 13.0**:

```
String foo = "Something";
String bar = "Other";

if (foo.equals(bar));
{
   System.out.println("Face palm");
}
```

Sadly, the **above** comparison **succeeds** and the "Face palm" is printed out.
What causes this behavior is the existence of the **semi-colon** in the end of the if statement.

The correct way of doing this is:

```
String foo = "Something";
String bar = "Other";

if (foo.equals(bar))
{
   System.out.println("Face palm");
}
```

Could anyone explain why Java behaves like this ?

Could that be just an uncaught syntax error by the compiler ?

Comment: `if (foo.equals(bar));` is equivalent to `if (foo.equals(bar)) {}`

Comment: some IDEs have an option to signal an empty statement (as warning or even as error)

Comment: It is not really a syntax *error* per se. `if` (and `while` and `for`) require a *statement* to follow them. It just so happens that `;` by itself is a valid statement. There are uses of if/for/while with an empty statement (if the expressions have side effects), but they are somewhat confusing.

Answer (score 4):

It does not mean that *comparison succeeds* - basically you just created `if` statement with empty body and then opened the local anonymous code block (starting from `{`)

The `Face palm` value in this case will be printed out always - no matter what the condition result will be

Read more here:

- [Semicolon at end of 'if' statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14112515/semicolon-at-end-of-if-statement)
- [Anonymous code blocks in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563030/anonymous-code-blocks-in-java)