# The Java search: "block"

Tags: java, search

Has anyone ever seen the following in Java?

```
public void methodName(){ 
   search:
     for(Type[] t : Type[] to){
       do something...
   }
}
```

Can someone point me to documentation on the use of "search:" in this context?  Searching for "search:" has not been productive.

Thanks

Comment: Where did you see this in the first place?

Comment: It's a label; yes, I've seen them. They're relatively uncommon, but occasionally quite useful. They can also be used with `continue`, although all the answers so far only mention `break`.

Comment: This would be of use to you if you wish to use labels in the future:  [http://stackoverflow.com/q/205458/1079354](http://stackoverflow.com/q/205458/1079354).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a *label*. From [§14.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.7) of the Java Language specification:

> Statements may have label prefixes...
>
> *(Boring grammar omitted, pain to mark up)*
>
> Unlike C and C++, the Java programming language has no `goto` statement; identifier statement labels are used with `break` (§14.15) or `continue` (§14.16) statements appearing anywhere within the labeled statement.

One place you frequently see labels is in nested loops, where you may want to break out of both loops early:

```
void foo() {
    int i, j;

    outerLoop:                     // <== label
    for (i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        innerLoop:                 // <== another label
        for (j = 0; j < 100; ++j) {
            if (/*...someCondition...*/) {
                break outerLoop;   // <== use the label
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Normally that `break` in the inner loop would break just the inner loop, but not the outer one. But because it's a  *directed* `break` using a label, it breaks the outer loop.

Comment: You folks are awesome.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of a labelled loop.

It allows you to `break` or `continue` the target loop instead of your current loop.

```
Outer:
    for(int intOuter=0; intOuter < intArray.length ; intOuter++)
    {
      Inner:
      for(int intInner=0; intInner < intArray[intOuter].length; intInner++)
      {
        if(intArray[intOuter][intInner] == 30)
        {
          blnFound = true;
          break Outer; // this line breaks the outer loop instead of the inner loop.
        }  

      }
    }
```

example taken from : http://www.java-examples.com/java-break-statement-label-example

Answer (score 0):

It is a Java label as defined here in JLS: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/statements.html#78994